# Can't use changeable field in Mongoose Sort

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Hello i want to use Mongoose sort but i have a problem when i want to change my sorting with arguments it doesn't work. For example

```
Users.find().sort({sortBy: 1})
```

Its not working at all. Whats the problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems in your code:

**1. You are not specifying what field to sort by:**

You forgot to change the `sortBy` field in your sort object to the wanted field to sort by.
For example, if you want to sort your users by name it will look like:

```js
User.find().sort({name: 1})
```

**2. You are not executing your query**

You need to execute the query using the `.exec(callback)` function.
Your code will look like:

```js
Users.find().sort({sortBy: 1}).exec((err, documents) => {
    // Your logic
})
```

You can also use the await keyword to get your data without a callback function.

```js
const users = await Users.find().sort({sortBy: 1}).exec();
```

Just note that if you decide to use the await option it needs to be in an async function.

Comment: Tnx but sortBy is something i get from client and i don't know what is it.

Comment: If that's the case then you are not creating the sort object correctly.
In JavaScript, keys are written not only as string, so what you will get is not the key with the variable value but an object with `{'sortBy': 1}` every time no matter what is in  the sortBy variable. What you need to do to solve this is to use:
`{[sortBy]: 1}`
The [] tells javascript to take the value of the sortBy variable and put it as the key in the object you are creating.

Comment: Tnx thats what i needed. :)